# How to mark a table as pre-populated with postgresql logical replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, transactional-replication

I accidentally loaded data into a table before setting up a logical replication subscription for it and now I'm getting errors when I try to sync it (duplicate key already exists).

I can't delete the rows because "cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint".

Is there a way to tell the subscription that the table was pre-synced or pre-populated?

We're getting lots of logs lines like:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this fixed using a bit of a hack. Basically, drop the table from the publication, refresh the publication from the subscriber, add the table to the publication again, then refresh the publication again, but with `copy_data=false`:

1. drop the table from the publication.

   ```
   alter publication my-publication drop table only my-table ;
   ```
2. Refresh the subscription.

   ```
   ALTER SUBSCRIPTION my-subscription REFRESH PUBLICATION;
   ```

   The log lines seem to stop at this point. Good!
3. Add the table to the publication.

   ```
   alter publication my-publication add table only my-table ;
   ```
4. Refresh the subscription with `copy_data (false)`

   ```
    ALTER SUBSCRIPTION my-subscription REFRESH PUBLICATION with (copy_data = false);
   ```

This seems to work, though it seems like it'd be problematic on a table that was changing rapidly.

It'd be nice to put this in a transaction somehow, but the commands are being run alternately on the publisher and the subscriber, so I don't know how that'd work.